# Window function in spark , group by and replace column values with maximum rank

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have the below dataset in spark

```
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+
|ID |PState|MState |dt      |TS                      |
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+
|1  |Iowa  |Kansas |20240212|null                    |
|1  |Iowa  |CA     |20250212|null                    |
|2  |Maine |Chicago|20240212|2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z|
|2  |NJ    |NY     |20250212|null                    |
|3  |CA    |MS     |20240212|null                    |
|3  |NJ    |NY     |20240212|null                    |
|3  |NJ    |WV     |20240212|null                    |
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+
```

After applying the rank on the DT column, I got the below Dataset

```
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+--------+
|ID |PState|MState |dt      |TS                      |dateRank|
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+--------+
|1  |Iowa  |Kansas |20240212|null                    |1       |
|1  |Iowa  |CA     |20250212|null                    |2       |
|2  |Maine |Chicago|20240212|2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z|1       |
|2  |NJ    |NY     |20250212|null                    |2       |
|3  |CA    |MS     |20240212|null                    |1       |
|3  |NJ    |NY     |20240212|null                    |1       |
|3  |NJ    |WV     |20240212|null                    |1       |
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+--------+
```

Here's my code for generating `dateRank` column:

```java
WindowSpec dateSpec = Window.partitionBy(col("ID"))
                    .orderBy(col("dt").asc());

Dataset<Row> dateRankedDS = df.withColumn(
    "dateRank",
    functions.rank().over(dateSpec).cast(DataTypes.StringType));

dateRankedDS.show(false);
```

I wanted to group by on ID and select the maximum rank and replace the maximum rank's `PState` and `MState` to other ID's column values such that my output looks like

```
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+
|ID |PState|MState |dt      |TS                      |
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+
|1  |Iowa  |CA.    |20240212|null                    |
|1  |Iowa  |CA     |20250212|null                    |
|2  |NJ    |NY.    |20240212|2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z|
|2  |NJ    |NY     |20250212|null                    |
|3  |CA    |MS     |20240212|null                    |
|3  |NJ    |NY     |20240212|null                    |
|3  |NJ    |WV     |20240212|null                    |
+---+------+-------+--------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the answer? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

After computing the `dateRank` (that I would not cast to string for the comparison to work later), you could create a `replacement` column that would contain the `PState` and `MState` values corresponding the the maximum rank. Then, you could replace the `PState` and `MState` that have a lower rank with these values. It would go as follows:

In scala:

```scala
val dateSpec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("dt")
val dateSpecNoOrder = Window.partitionBy("ID")

df
    .withColumn("dateRank", rank over dateSpec)
    .withColumn("replacement", max(struct(col("dateRank"), col("PState"), col("MState"))) over dateSpecNoOrder)
    .withColumn("PState", when(col("dateRank") < col("replacement.dateRank"), col("replacement.PState")).otherwise(col("PState")))
    .withColumn("MState", when(col("dateRank") < col("replacement.dateRank"), col("replacement.MState")).otherwise(col("MState")))
    .show(false)
```

```
+---+------+------+--------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
|ID |PState|MState|dt      |TS                      |dateRank|replacement  |
+---+------+------+--------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
|1  |Iowa  |CA    |20240212|null                    |1       |{2, Iowa, CA}|
|1  |Iowa  |CA    |20250212|null                    |2       |{2, Iowa, CA}|
|2  |NJ    |NY    |20240212|2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z|1       |{2, NJ, NY}  |
|2  |NJ    |NY    |20250212|null                    |2       |{2, NJ, NY}  |
|3  |CA    |MS    |20240212|null                    |1       |{1, NJ, WV}  |
|3  |NJ    |NY    |20240212|null                    |1       |{1, NJ, WV}  |
|3  |NJ    |WV    |20240212|null                    |1       |{1, NJ, WV}  |
+---+------+------+--------+------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

In java:

```java
WindowSpec dateSpec = Window.partitionBy(col("ID")).orderBy(col("dt"));
WindowSpec dateSpecNoOrder = Window.partitionBy(col("ID"));

df
    .withColumn("dateRank", rank over dateSpec)
    .withColumn("replacement", max(struct(col("dateRank"), col("PState"), col("MState"))).over(dateSpecNoOrder))
    .withColumn("PState", when(col("dateRank").lt(col("replacement.dateRank"), col("replacement.PState"))).otherwise(col("PState")))
    .withColumn("MState", when(col("dateRank").lt(col("replacement.dateRank"), col("replacement.MState"))).otherwise(col("MState")))
    .show(false);
```